# Controlled/manual error/recovery handling in stream-based applications

Tags: apache-spark, error-handling, apache-kafka, stream, apache-flink

I am working on an application based on `Apache Flink`, which makes use of `Apache Kafka` for input and out. Possibly this application will be ported to `Apache Spark`, so I have added this as a tag as well, and the question remains the same.

I have the requirement that all incoming messages received via kafka must be processed in-order, as well safely be stored in a persistence layer (database), and no message must get lost.

The streaming-part in this application is rather trivial/small, as the main logic will boil down to something like:

```
environment.addSource(consumer)    // 1) DataStream[Option[Elem]]
  .filter(_.isDefined)             // 2) discard unparsable messages
  .map(_.get)                      // 3) unwrap Option
  .map(InputEvent.fromXml(_))      // 4) convert from XML to internal representation
  .keyBy(_.id)                     // 5) assure in-order processing on logical-key level
  .map(new DBFunction)             // 6) database lookup, store of update and additional enrichment
  .map(InputEvent.toXml(_))        // 7) convert back to XML
  .addSink(producer)               // 8) attach kafka producer sink
```

Now, during this pipeline, several error situations *could* occur:

- the database becomes unavailable (shutdown, tablespace full, ...)
- changes cannot be stored because of logical errors (from column format)
- the kafka producer cannot send a message because of broker inavailability

and probably other situations.

Now my question is, *how* can I assure consistency as per the above in those situations, when I in fact would have to do something like:

1. Stream-Operator 6) detects a problem (DB unavailable)
2. The DB-connection of the `DBFunction` object must be recovered, which might only succeed after some minutes
3. This means that overall processing must be suspended, at best for the whole pipeline, so that incoming messages are lot loaded into memory
4. Resume processing after database has been recovered. Processing must resume exactly with the message which encountered the problem at 1)

Now I know that there is at least 2 tools regarding failure handling:

1. kafka consumer offsets
2. apache flink checkpoints

However, searching the docs, I fail to see how either of those could be used in the middle of stream processing from within a single operator.

So, what would be the recommended strategies for fine-grained error handling and recovery in a streaming application?

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

The keyBy is not going to help ensure in-order processing. If anything, it may interleave events from different Kafka partitions (which may have been in-order within each partition), thereby creating out-of-orderness where it didn't previously exist. It's hard to comment more specifically about how you might guarantee in-order processing without understanding how many FlinkKafkaConsumer instances you intend to use, how many partitions each one will be consuming from, how the keys are distributed across the Kafka partitions, and why you think a keyBy is necessary -- but if you set things up correctly, preserving order may be achievable. [reinterpretAsKeyedStream](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/experimental.html) can be helpful here, but this feature is difficult to understand, and tricky to use correctly.

You could use Flink's [AsyncFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html) to manage the connection to the external DB in a fault tolerant, exactly-once, manner.

Flink doesn't support fine-grained recovery in a systematic way -- its checkpoints are global snapshots of the state of the entire distributed cluster, and are designed to be used during recovery as a monolithic, self-consistent, snapshot. If your job fails, normally the only recourse is to restart from a checkpoint, which will involve rewinding input queues (to the offsets stored in the checkpoint), replaying the events since those offsets, re-issuing the DB lookups (which the async function will do automatically), and using kafka transactions to achieve end-to-end exactly once semantics. However, in the case of embarrassingly parallel jobs, it is sometimes possible to take advantage of [fine-grained recovery](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-1+%3A+Fine+Grained+Recovery+from+Task+Failures).

Comment: It is my understanding that `keyBy` leads to the same key beeing processed by always the same instance of operators, no matter what the parallelism is, and thus, ensures in-order processing in the operator-scope. Of course, `keyBy` will not be ever capable of bringing something in-order which is supplied via kafka *out of order*.
My requirements in this regards are simple: messages with the same logical key must be processed in-order, and it is up to me to decide how to set up kafka topics, consumers, and the flink-application. Currently, there is exactly 1 `FlinkKafkaConsumer011` instance.

Comment: ... and 1 partition on the topic. 

Regarding recovery: Of course the application is going to be a 24/7 online application, and most likely there will be no human support available at all times. Thus, relying solely on restarting from checkpoints in case of failure (= manual task) is not a way to go. I am rather trying to achieve a stable-in-all-cases implementation which does not require user interaction, or, in the worst case, brings everything to a halt in case the error is not recoverable. This is what my question was related to, *how* to bring everything to a halt automatically.

Comment: To be more precise, I'm lacking the understanding of what flink is going to to in the following situations: 1) operator thread is *blocked* by falling into a loop which tries to recover a database connection 2) operator thread is *blocked* because some unrecoverable error was detected, and processing must be halted. 
The topic is a bit more complicated as all my operator are stateless, but most likely I am going to follow Fabian Hueske's advice as given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54986886/understanding-flink-savepoints-checkpoints/54987342#54987342 and implement transations.

Comment: Restarting from checkpoints is a fully automatic process, and you have a fair bit of control over the automated restart policy. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/restart_strategies.html No human intervention is required.

Comment: If you make sure that for any given key, all of its events are in the same kafka partition, then they will naturally stay in order because they will all be consumed by the same FlinkKafkaConsumer011 instance. In that case a keyBy won't shuffle them together with events for the same key from other partitions (which would lead to out-of-orderness).

Comment: Okay so we have the same understanding of the `keyBy`, thats good :)

Comment: Regarding the automatic restart: I am referring to non-crash situations. In this case, the automatic restart wont kick in, since nothing crashed. In my example above, the `.map(new DBFunction)` might fail, which will require appropriate handling of the error situation.