# Understanding flink savepoints & checkpoints

Tags: scala, persistence, apache-flink, failover, checkpoint

Considering an Apache Flink streaming-application with a pipeline like this:

```
Kafka-Source -> flatMap 1 -> flatMap 2 -> flatMap 3 -> Kafka-Sink
```

where every `flatMap` function is a non-stateful operator (e.g. the normal `.flatMap` function of a `Datastream`).

How do checkpoints/savepoints work, in case an incoming message will be pending at `flatMap 3`? Will the message be reprocessed after restart beginning from `flatMap 1` or will it skip to `flatMap 3`?

I am a bit confused, because the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/stream/state/) seems to refer to application state as what I can use in stateful operators, but I don't have stateful operators in my application.
Is the "processing progress" saved & restored *at all*, or will the whole pipeline be re-processed after a failure/restart?

And this there a difference between a failure (-> flink restores from checkpoint) and manual restart using savepoints regarding my previous questions?

I tried finding out myself (with enabled checkpointing using `EXACTLY_ONCE` and rocksdb-backend) by placing a `Thread.sleep()` in `flatMap 3` and then cancelling the job with a savepoint. However this lead to the `flink` commandline tool hanging until the `sleep` was over, and even then `flatMap 3` was executed and even sent out to the sink ***before*** the job got cancelled. So it seems I can not manually force this situation to analyze flink's behaviour.

In case "processing progress" is not saved/covered by the checkpointing/savepoints as I described above, how could I make sure for every message reaching my pipeline that any given operator (flatmap 1/2/3) is never re-processed in a restart/failure situation?

Answer (score 1):

When a checkpoint is taken, every task (parallel instance of an operator) checkpoints its state. In your example, the three flatmap operators are stateless, so there is no state to be checkpointed. The Kafka source is stateful and checkpoints the reading offsets for all partitions.

In case of a failure, the job is recovered and all tasks load their state which means in case of the source operator that the reading offsets are reset. Hence, the application will reprocess all events since the last checkpoint.

In order to achieve end-to-end exactly-once, you need a special sink connector that offers either transaction support (e.g., for Kafka) or supports idempotent writes.

Comment: I see. So basically I would need to implement: https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html. Thanks for your response.
I had a similar question also regarding failure situations here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444938/controlled-manual-error-recovery-handling-in-stream-based-applications Do you maybe have advice for this topic too?